# Implement a Properties Filter in .NET

Tags: .net, algorithm, reflection

I have to filter a list of objects.

The filter should be composed by users using logical OR / AND operators, and grouping using brackets.

say, something like this:

[image]

Say, we have object MyObj and its properties Prop1, Prop2, Prop3

Having myObjList the user could filter elements that Prop1 == aValue AND Prop2 < otherValue OR Prop2 > thirdvalue

Is there some known (reflection) mechanisms that permits to manage this kind of filtering operations?

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic linq to construct filter statements at runtime agaist object list.

Here is a [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) to Scott Guthrie's blog that explains implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Build expression trees, then compile them to give you a delegate which you can apply to the objects you want to filter.

MSDN has some introductory coverage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is another [link](http://tomasp.net/articles/dynamic-linq-queries.aspx) to implement dynamic linq, using more of a [specification pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern).