# Expression tree for String.IndexOf method

Tags: c#, reflection, expression-trees, linq-expressions

How should I construct Expression tree for `string.IndexOf("substring", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`?

I can get it working without the second argument: `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`. These are my attempts so far:

```
var methodCall = typeof (string).GetMethod("IndexOf", new[] {typeof (string)});
Expression[] parms = new Expression[]{right, Expression.Constant("StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase", typeof (Enum))};
var exp =  Expression.Call(left, methodCall, parms);
return exp;
```

Also tried this:

```
var methodCall = typeof (string).GetMethod(method, new[] {typeof (string)});
Expression[] parms = new Expression[]{right, Expression.Parameter(typeof(Enum) , "StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase")};
var exp =  Expression.Call(left, methodCall, parms);
return exp;
```

Please remember that I can get it working if I ignore the `OrdinalIgnoreCase` parameter.

Thanks

Comment: As ever, when you have problems you should say what's going wrong with what you've tried - do you get an exception, a compile-time error, just wrong behaviour? If it's an error of some kind, what's the error?

Comment: Sorry. I'll keep that in mind next time when asking questions. I was getting an ArgumentException.

Comment: Should help: [how-do-i-create-an-expression-tree-to-represent-string-containsterm-in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278684/how-do-i-create-an-expression-tree-to-represent-string-containsterm-in-c)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suspect there are two problems.

The first is the way you're getting the method - you're *asking* for a method with only a single string parameter, instead of one with two parameters:

```
var methodCall = typeof (string).GetMethod("IndexOf",
                            new[] { typeof (string), typeof(StringComparison) });
```

The second is the *value* you're giving - it should be the actual value of the constant, not a string:

```
Expression[] parms = new Expression[] { right, 
    Expression.Constant(StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) };
```

EDIT: Here's a complete working sample:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var method = typeof (string).GetMethod("IndexOf",
                new[] { typeof (string), typeof(StringComparison) });

        var left = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "left");
        var right = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "right");

        Expression[] parms = new Expression[] { right, 
                Expression.Constant(StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) };

        var call = Expression.Call(left, method, parms);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, string, int>>
            (call, left, right);

        var compiled = lambda.Compile();
        Console.WriteLine(compiled.Invoke("hello THERE", "lo t"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do same for `contains` method?

Comment: @atp9: Yes. What have you tried, and what went wrong?

Comment: I have tried something like this:`MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string),typeof(StringComparison) });
                var expressionbody = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(prop, method, new [] { valuetocompare, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) });` But this one gives me an error

Comment: @atp9: Given that comments aren't really good for extended pieces of code, I suggest you ask a new question with a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do it would be to get it via a lambda like this:

```
//the compiler will convert the lambda into an expression
Expression<Func<string, string, int>> expression = (s1, s2) => s1.IndexOf(s2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
//compile the expression so we can call it
var func = expression.Compile();
//outputs 2
Console.WriteLine(func("Case Sensitive", "se sensitive"));
```

This is much more readable and maintainable than manually building an expression tree.

I'm constantly surprised by the amount of people who dive straight into manually building expression trees.  There's no need to when you can get the compiler to do the work for you.

Comment: +1, there's no reason to build the expression tree manually when the compiler can do it for you

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, but we can't see where `left` and `right` are coming from here... they're presumably of type `Expression`, not `string`.

Comment: May be this is the better way but the library that I'm working on (https://github.com/ashokgelal/NetFilterFramework) has been built on by manually building an expression tree. For now I just need to add a string comparison method call but may be I need to refactor/ rewrite everything using lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check the rest of it, but if only the enum poses problems:

```
Expression.Constant(StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

or

```
Expression.Constant(Enum.Parse(typeof(StringComparison), "OrdinalIgnoreCase"), typeof(Enum));
```

And you have more options. Or check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077056/dynamic-expression-using-linq-how-to-find-the-kitchens/7077225#7077225).

Edit: forgot paranthesis.